# .Machine$double.eps larger than necessary?

Tags: r

The documentation describes `.Machine$double.eps` as *The smallest positive floating-point number x such that `1 + x != 1`*. So I would expect the following to produce a 1:

```
options(digits=17)
1 + .Machine$double.eps
# [1] 1.0000000000000002
```

but it doesn't. It appears that I have to go as low as `0.5*.Machine$double.eps` before I get the expected round-off to one. Am I misunderstanding something about `.Machine$double.eps`? Is this platform-dependent? (sessionInfo() below)

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2
```

Thank you

Comment: Is something missing from your first example? It looks like you're adding `1 + eps`, which should indeed not be 1...

Comment: OK, right 1 + eps should not be 1. But 1 + 0.99eps should be, right?

Comment: I'm thinking that that may be an error in the R documentation. Note how [Java defines its analog differently](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp%28double%29): "the positive distance between this floating-point value and the double value next larger in magnitude".

Comment: double.eps is 2^-52, the smallest value up until which you *can distinguish* - meaning 2^-52+1 != 1 (would be possible to tell). But 1+2^-53 will be = 1 - not possible to distinguish. Isn't this what the first line from OP says? So why are you expecting the result to be 1?

Comment: Thanks Owen and Arun. I get it now. So, yes, I certainly _did_ misunderstand eps. Need to learn to read the docs more carefully.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just because it's interesting, here is [the code R uses to calculate eps](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/platform.c) (extracted into its own program):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double temp, tempa, a;
    double eps;

    double one = 1;
    double zero = one - one;
    double beta = 2;

    a = 1.38777878078144568e-17;
    for(;;) {
        temp = one + a;
        if (temp - one != zero)
            break;
        a = a * beta;
    }
    eps = a;

    printf("%e\n", eps);
}
```

It yields 2.22e-16 as documented.

Note that it jumps by a factor of 2 each time -- so it's not actually going to find the strictly *smallest* floating point where `1 + x` isn't `1`. But it is going to find the smallest one on that ladder of powers of 2.

So, I would say that strictly speaking the documentation is not quite accurate, because it is indeed true that `0.75*eps + 1 != 1` and `0.75*eps < eps`.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you misunderstood the documentation.  Note that it says that it is the smallest `x` such that `1 + x != 1`

So read that carefully - if we add 1 to `.Machine$double.eps` then we should NOT get 1 back.  So the result you got was as expected.

Comment: I'm still confused, or still misreading.  Doesn't `x <- .Machine$double.eps; y <- 0.7*x; 1+y!=1 ## TRUE; y<x ## TRUE` falsify the statement that `.Machine$double.eps` is the **smallest** positive floating-point number such that `1+x !=1` ... ???

Comment: @BenBolker, I guess the confusion is because OP chose a poor example. For OP's case, what Dason says about "it being not equal to 1 is right" is right. But him quoting the documentation isn't as it's not entirely true as Owen points out.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the algorithm posted by @Owen searches and finds that number `x`, for which

```
(x+1)-1 == (x*0.51+1)-1 !=  (x*0.5+1)-1
```

@Ben, true, `x*0.6 < x`, but after evaluating `x+1`, `'x'`, i.e. the residual part, becomes `.Machine$double.eps` or `0` due to the limits of double precision floating-point arithmetics.

In my view, `.Machine$double.eps` is the smallest representation of a residual of unity subtraction.

So, `.Machine$double.eps` indeed is *the smallest positive floating-point number x such that 1 + x != 1* according to the significant digits and for the exponent being 1e0.

To elaborate, please note that according to [ANSI/IEEE-754 standard](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), in 64 bit floating point representation, 52bits are reserved for the mantissa (signif digits), 11 bit for the exponent, and 1 for sign. 
As a result of this, the smallest possible number (better: accuracy) regarding the mantissa is in bits:

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` (52 if counting right)

This is `.Machine$double.eps` and consequently,  `log2(.Machine$double.eps)` returns -52.

(in case of **non** 64bit double floating point it will return something else)

Further, since

`.Machine$double.eps + 1 = +1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e00000000000`

it's obvious that there cant be a smaller number than `.Machine$double.eps` for which `x+1!=1`, because every smaller number will either be rounded to `2^-52` or `0` upon addition.